# Using java to encrypt integers

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, integer, arrays

I'm trying to encrypt some integers in java using java.security and javax.crypto.

The problem seems to be that the Cipher class only encrypts byte arrays.  I can't directly convert an integer to a byte string (or can I?).  What is the best way to do this?

Should I convert the integer to a string and the string to byte[]?  This seems too inefficient.

Does anyone know a quick/easy or efficient way to do it?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

jbu

Comment: Hmm.. are you going between different Endianness? If so that would cause those integers to be incorrect when you converted them back from the byte array..

Comment: Apparerntly "Java virtual machine always used big-endian", so I guess it's not an issue.

Answer (score 11):

You can turn ints into a byte[] using a DataOutputStream, like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream (baos);
dos.writeInt (i);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
// do encryption
```

Then to decrypt it later:

```
byte[] decrypted = decrypt (data);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream (data);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (bais);
int j = dis.readInt();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use BigInteger for conversion:

```
 BigInteger.valueOf(integer).toByteArray();
```

Comment: you're creating an un needed intermediate string object in this process.

Answer (score 5):

Just use NIO. It's designed for this specific purpose. ByteBuffer and IntBuffer will do what you need quickly, efficiently, and elegantly. It'll handle big/little endian conversion, "direct" buffers for high performance IO, and you can even mix data types into the byte buffer.

**Convert integers into bytes:**

```
ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4*theIntArray.length);
IntBuffer ibuffer = bbuffer.asIntBuffer(); //wrapper--doesn't allocate more memory
ibuffer.put(theIntArray);                  //add your int's here; can use 
                                           //array if you want
byte[] rawBytes = bbuffer.array();         //returns array backed by bbuffer--
                                           //i.e. *doesn't* allocate more memory
```

**Convert bytes into integers:**

```
ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBytes);
IntBuffer ibuffer = bbuffer.asIntBuffer();
while(ibuffer.hasRemaining())
   System.out.println(ibuffer.get());      //also has bulk operators
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following code that may help you, since Integer in Java is always 4 bytes long.

```
public static byte[] intToFourBytes(int i, boolean bigEndian) {  
    if (bigEndian) {  
        byte[] data = new byte[4];  
        data[3] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);  
        data[2] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF);  
        data[1] = (byte) ((i >> 16) & 0xFF);  
        data[0] = (byte) ((i >> 24) & 0xFF);  
        return data;  

    } else {  
        byte[] data = new byte[4];  
        data[0] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);  
        data[1] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0xFF);  
        data[2] = (byte) ((i >> 16) & 0xFF);  
        data[3] = (byte) ((i >> 24) & 0xFF);  
        return data;  
    }  
}
```

You can find more information about the bigEndian parameter here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0):

create a 4-byte array and copy the int to the array in 4 steps, with bitwise ANDs and bitshifting, like Paulo said.

But remember that block algorithms such as AES and DES work with 8 or 16 byte blocks so you will need to pad the array to what the algorithm needs. Maybe leave the first 4 bytes of an 8-byte array as 0's, and the other 4 bytes contain the integer.

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
    Integer.toString(int).getBytes();
```

Make sure you use your original int and getBytes() will return a byte array. No need to do anything else complicated.

To convert back:

```
    Integer.parseInt(encryptedString);
```

Answer (score -1):

My Simple Solution is that Encrypt Integer to the String by shifting ASCII Value of the Integer by the secret key you Provide.

Here is the Solution:

```
public String encodeDiscussionId(int Id) {

    String tempEn = Id + "";
    String encryptNum ="";
    for(int i=0;i<tempEn.length();i++) {
        int a = (int)tempEn.charAt(i);
        a+=148113;
        encryptNum +=(char)a;
    }
    return encryptNum;
}

public Integer decodeDiscussionId(String encryptText) {

    String decodeText = "";
    for(int i=0;i<encryptText.length();i++) {
        int a= (int)encryptText.charAt(i);
        a -= 148113;
        decodeText +=(char)a;
    }
    int decodeId = Integer.parseInt(decodeText);
    return decodeId;
}
```

Steps to Encode:

1. Here, First you convert the Given Integer into String by: `String temp = givenInt + ""`
2. Scan each character of String, Read ASCII of that character and add it with secret key as 148113 in this case.
3. Convert shifted `Integer` into Character and concatenate to the `String encryptNum` and finally return it.

Steps to Decode:

1. Scan each character of String, Read ASCII of that character and subtract it with secret key as previous.
2. Convert that value to character and concatenate with `decodeText`.

*As previous encode output is always `String '???'` and vary according to number of digits  of input `Id`.*