# PHP encode methods

Tags: php

Is it possible to encode user's ID# to text value?

For example if the user ID# is '50624' is it possible to convert it to 7 characters text value, something like 'DEGXCVG'?

If I use MD5 for this function I get 16-byte hash value.
The result value should not be longer than 7 or 8  characters.

Edit:
I want that each user has a different text code obtained from the id number.

Comment: What is the value range of your input values?

Comment: Values are from 0 to 100.000 +

Comment: So it’s unsigned 32 bit integer values?

Comment: So it’s 10<sup>6</sup> < 2<sup>20</sup>. And to represent 20 bits with 7 characters you would need 20/7 < 3 bits/character (2<sup>3</sup>=8, so `0`…`7` would suffice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a hash function such as MD5 can be used instead of encryption, you could try [`crc32()`](http://php.net/crc32) instead, which produces shorter (but with much higher chances of collisions) strings.

---

If you just care about encoding, you could do something simpler:

```
function encode($id) {
  $id_str = (string) $id;
  $offset = rand(0, 9);
  $encoded = chr(79 + $offset);
  for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($id_str); $i < $len; ++$i) {
    $encoded .= chr(65 + $id_str[$i] + $offset);
  }
  return $encoded;
}

function decode($encoded) {
  $offset = ord($encoded[0]) - 79;
  $encoded = substr($encoded, 1);
  for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($encoded); $i < $len; ++$i) {
    $encoded[$i] = ord($encoded[$i]) - $offset - 65;
  }
  return (int) $encoded;
}
```

Example:

```
var_dump(encode(50624)); // string(6) "TKFLHJ"
```

---

Encryption version:

```
define('CRYPTO_KEY', 'Secret key');

function encrypt($id) {
  return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, CRYPTO_KEY, (string) $id, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}

function decrypt($encrypted) {
  return (int) base64_decode(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, CRYPTO_KEY, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}
```

Comment: @rdineiu - This is nice solution. But I get some strange characters as result. What can be the problem?

Comment: @Sergio, it's the encrypted string. Encode it with something like `base64_encode()` or `urlencode()`. Check out the last part of the example.

Comment: @rdineiu - I did that but I get varchar value. I need result value without numbers.

Comment: @Sergio, if you call `base64_encode(encrypt(50624))` you will get the string `MCLLRJooaoQ=`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @rdineiu - yes, but for base64_encode(encrypt(50625)) I get 'SR2rpy5Ij00='. I don't want numbers in result value.

Comment: @Sergio, I see. I added an encoding option to the examples as well. It won't have any number in it. It's not encrypted or secure either.

Comment: Also, the first method, with encryption, won't work, because you need to send the $iv as well, which will make the string 16 bytes. Removed the example.

Comment: @rdineiu - The encryption method was fine if I can find the solution for result value length (max 7 characters) and to remove numbers from it.

Comment: @Sergio, can't really do much to get the size to max. 7 characters with encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the integer into a Hexadecimal value using [dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

Anyway if u able to explain your scenario more clear, we may able to provide best solution

Comment: @gumbo Yes, since i didn't know his exact requirement, i just suggested a encoded solution. Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish with this?

First of all MD5 is not "encryption" it is a one-way hash function. It cannot be reversed. If that is OK for you, why not simply hash your IDs and then take 7-8 characters from the hash? You could MD5 your ID and then take the first 8 characters of the resulting MD5.

Comment: In that case, if I use first 7 characters from hash, what are the chances that some other user have the same hash code?  I want that each user has a different text code obtained from the id number.

Comment: It's very unlikely but not impossible that 2 users would have the same value. You might be better off converting your int to its hexadecimal string equivalent. Any time you are casting a something into a fixed width you necessarily have a FINITE number of possible outputs, so there  is no way to map an infinite number of inputs to a finite number of outputs WITHOUT a repeating value (collision).

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is called base transformation ... your ID is a base 10 number with the numbers from 0 to 9 represent the digits of that base.

other common bases would be 2 (binary), 16(hexadecimal), or 64(often called base 64 encoding) but you could also take some other base if you like.

i've written a somewhat general base transform code in c# (uint to whatever base string and vice versa) ... shouldn't be that hard to port it to php:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var item in UintToOtherBase(0xDEADBEEF, "01").Reverse())
    {
        Console.Write(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(OtherBaseToInt(UintToOtherBase(0xDEADBEEF, "01"), "01").ToString("X"));
    Console.WriteLine(UintToOtherBase(0xDEADBEEF, "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));
}

public static string UintToOtherBase(uint input, string newBaseDigits)
{
    char[] uniqueDigits = newBaseDigits.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray();
    uint newBase = (uint)uniqueDigits.Length;
    if (newBase < 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("otherBaseDigits has to contain at least 2 unique chars");
    }
    else
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (input != 0)
        {
            uint digit = input % newBase;
            sb.Append(uniqueDigits[digit]);
            input /= newBase;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
public static uint OtherBaseToInt(string input, string otherBaseDigits)
{
    string uniqueDigits = new String(otherBaseDigits.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray());
    int otherBase = uniqueDigits.Length;
    if (otherBase < 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("otherBaseDigits has to contain at least 2 unique chars");
    }
    else if (input.ToCharArray().Any(x => !uniqueDigits.Contains(x)))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("an input char was not found in otherBaseDigits");
    }
    else
    {
        uint result = 0;
        int pow = 0;
        foreach (var c in input)
        {
            result += (uint)uniqueDigits.IndexOf(c) * (uint)Math.Pow(otherBase, pow++);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

//edit:

but just to point it out, this is an encoding ... no encryption

Answer (score 0):

If obscuring is good enough, convert the number to [base62](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450) after permuting its bits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can design your own encryption method or take part of md5 hash value.
Btw, the way to encrypt an integer has been discussed in the following post.

[Way to encrypt a single int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959916/way-to-encrypt-a-single-int)